# My Operation in a WCF service's call stack gets called, but doesn't finish

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I am supporting a Silverlight 4.0 application, which makes a call to a WCF service. As I debug the service, hosted locally on IIS, it makes it to this method but apparently leaves the method without returning from the end. I don't see any exceptions being called.

This is the method in a business class, which stops short of returning to the calling method.

```
public string ExecuteMyPortalNonQuery(string CommandConfig, params object[] commandParams)
    {
        MyCompany.MyPortal.DataAccess.SQLDataAccess objSQLDatAcces = new SQLDataAccess();
        objSQLDatAcces.connection = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["MyPortalSQLConnection"];

        string SqlQueryString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings[CommandConfig];
        if (commandParams != null && commandParams.Length > 0)
            SqlQueryString = string.Format(SqlQueryString, commandParams);
        objSQLDatAcces.executeNonQuery(SqlQueryString);
        return ("SUCCESS");
    }
```

**Edit**

This is called by the operation contract

```
[OperationContract]
public string UpdateBlahblahList(int Id, int HierarchyId, int PagetypeId, string Name, string Asset, Boolean Default, string ServerName = "", string ServerConnectionString = "")
        {
            MyCompany.MyPortal.DataAccess.SAPAccess sp = new SAPAccess();
            if (Id != 0)
                return (sp.ExecuteMyPortalNonQuery("UpdateBlahblahList", Id, Name, Asset, (Default == true) ? 1 : 0, ServerName, ServerConnectionString));
            else
                return (sp.ExecuteMyPortalNonQuery("InsertBlahblahList", HierarchyId, PagetypeId, Name, Asset, (Default == true) ? 1 : 0, ServerName, ServerConnectionString));
        }
```

That is, when debugging, I find myself in the calling client right in the UpdateBlahblahCompleted method after stepping over the string formatting line, `SqlQueryString = string.Format(SqlQueryString, commandParams);`

The lines `objSQLDatAcces.executeNonQuery(SqlQueryString);` and `return ("SUCCESS");` are never reached.

To sum up:

1. Client calls UpdateBlahblahListAsync
2. In the service the [OperationContract] UpdateBlahblahList is reached
3. Service method UpdateBlahblahList calls ExecuteMyPortalNonQuery but doesn't finish
4. Client reenters with client_UpdateBlahblahListCompleted|

The net effect is that the database does not get updated.

Is debugging causing this? I'm debugging with two instances of VS 2010.

Can an exception be thrown that I haven't observed?

**Edit**

Thanks to Simon, I know where to observe the exception. In the Client's Async completed method's Args was the innermost exception message: "The remote server returned an error: NotFound.".

Here are the values for the two parameters:
UPDATE [dbo].[BlahblahXref] SET [PageId] = '{1}', [Name] = '{2}', [Asset] = '{3}', [Default] = '{4}', [ServerName]='{5}',[ServerConnectionString]='{6}'  WHERE Id={0}

with

commandParams [] = {375, "Test", "111", 0, "someServerName", "some long connection string"}

Comment: Is there any error in the client_UpdateBlahblahListCompleted args?

Comment: So that's where I should look. Yes.
**System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException** and the inner exception is **System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse**

Comment: There's some exception happening at the server, what you see on the client is mostly a consequence of it. Try enabling tracing on the server side - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx - and / or using a network tracing tool (such as Fiddler) to see the server response to the client. With that information we can probably help you more.

Comment: I failed to include the calling OperationContract on the server side. It is now included above. I didn't know C# allowed calling with a parameter list, where the method converts it to an object array. It doesn't surprise me that the CLR might be doing this behind the scenes, but it looks odd in the C#.

Comment: Incidentally the problem appears to be that I had fewer elements in the object array than places in the formatted string.

Comment: I wonder why SQL injection wasn't mentioned in relation to this question. What if the client decides to send some arbitrary sql as one of the (string) parameters?

Answer (score 0):

In the config file of your hosting application (web or console, whatever), you can put following lines to enable trace logging:

```
    <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
                <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="Services.svclog"  />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

then reproduce your bug again, open "Services.svclog", and you will be able to see details of wcf-calls including exception details.